# How to pass lua table to the c++ class Constructor using luaBridge?

Tags: lua, luabridge

This is what i want to make.

int lua:

```
object1 = MyObjectClass({1,2,3});
```

in c++

```
class MyObjectClass
{
public:
    MyObjectClass(/*How to passed lua table here?*/)
    {
    
    }
    void printmynum()
    {

    }
};


getGlobalNamespace(L)
    .beginClass<MyObjectClass>("MyObjectClass")
    .addConstructor<>()//???
    .addFunction("printmynum",&MyObjectClass::printmynum)
    .endClass();
```

I am sorry about the weak English skills.

I want to receive the table of lua from the constructor of MyObjectClass.

Comment: You can access Lua variables only via lua_State

Answer (score 0):

solved

```
class MyObjectClass
{
public:
    MyObjectClass(lua_State* L)
    {
        LuaRef param = LuaRef::fromStack(L, 2);
        if (param.isTable())
        {
            cout << param[1] << endl;
        }
    }
    void printmynum()
    {

    }
};


getGlobalNamespace(L)
.beginClass<MyObjectClass>("MyObjectClass")
    .addConstructor<void (*)(lua_State*)>()
    .addFunction("printmynum",&MyObjectClass::printmynum)
    .endClass();
```